# Ruby on Rails localization

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have to localize a web site with using the yml files. But I'm having problems with the following:

```
<tr>
    <td><%= link_to author.name, :action => 'show', :id => author %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', :action => 'edit', :id => author %></td>
    <td>
        <%= button_to t(:delete), {:action => 'destroy', :id => author},
        {:method => :delete,
        :confirm => "Are you sure you want to delete author #{author.name}?"} %>
        :confirm => t(:sure_delete_author, :authorname=>#{author.name}) } %>
    </td>
</tr>
```

`t(:delete)` works as it should, but the confirm doesn't. Left the original and the not working one.

Comment: you should remove line #7

Comment: Line 7 works, 8 doesn't. I just left 7 so that you can see what 8 has to do, but instead it gets an error on line 10..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to use string interpolation when there is no string (which seems to be a simple copy-and-paste problem)

Instead of

```
:authorname => #{author.name}
```

try one of these:

```
:authorname => "#{author.name}"
:authorname => author.name
```

The last one of course is to be preferred :)

PS: In my personal experience using the new Ruby 1.9 hash syntax removes a lot of visual clutter and makes spotting problems like this a lot easier.